# How to run OpenAPI YAML using Docker

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, openapi

I have an OpenAPI YAML file for a Java project. I am creating an AWS Lambda function and using API gateway deploying it on CloudFormation.

Is there a way I can use Docker to run the OpenAPI documentation locally?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "run the OpenAPI documentation locally"? If you are you referring to being able to browse the documentation, you can run https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-editor/ on your local machine. This will give you the same experience as https://editor.swagger.io/.

Comment: getting an error : The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

Comment: Looks like platform issue (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/2725). You can try this instead "docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor:next-v5" and then "docker run -p 8888:80 swaggerapi/swagger-editor:next-v5" and access the editor on "http://localhost:8888/" (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/3416#issuecomment-1310575668). This will be similar to https://editor-next.swagger.io/.